# How read excel with apache poi and save data in database Liferay service builder?

Tags: apache, liferay, apache-poi, liferay-service-builder

For example, I have a entity Product and I need import excel file and save in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach to do it is create a serveResource method in your controller that reads a binary file (you can obtain it with a form or through AJAX) with Apache POI the values from the excel file and store them into your Product List entity bean.

Also if you want you can modify your ProductLocalServiceImpl and rebuild the service, modifing the input parameter for that method and acepting a byte[].
Then you have to include all the logic in this method (is not recomendable).